# onclick action not working as intended with radio buttons

Tags: php, javascript, onclick, radio-button

For the last 4 hours I've been struggling to get something to work. I checked SO and other sources but couldn't find anything related to the subject. Here is the code:

```
<?php   
$email=$_SESSION['email'];
$query1="SELECT * FROM oferte WHERE  email='$email'";
$rez2=mysql_query($query1) or die (mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($rez2)>0)
{
while ($oferta = mysql_fetch_assoc($rez2))
{   
    $id=$oferta['id_oferta'];

    echo "<input type='radio' name='selectie' value='$id' id='$id'>&nbsp;<a href='oferta.php?id={$oferta['id_oferta']}'>{$oferta['denumire_locatie']}</a>";
    echo "</br>";
}

echo "</br>";


//echo "<input type=\"button\" id=\"cauta\" value=\"Vizualizeaza\" onclick=\"window.location.href='oferta.php?id={$oferta['id_oferta']}'\" />";
//echo "&nbsp;<input type=\"button\" id=\"cauta\"value=\"Modifica\" onclick=\"window.location.href='modifica.php?id={$oferta['id_oferta']}'\" />";
echo "&nbsp;<input type=\"button\" id=\"sterge\" value=\"Sterge\" onclick=\"window.location.href='delete.php?id=$id'\" />";
echo "</form>";     
echo "</div>";  
}
else
{

}
?>
```

The while drags all of the user's entries from the database and creates a radio button for each one of them with the value and id (because I don't really know which one is needed) equal to the entry's id from the db. I echoed that out and the id is displayed as it should so no problems there.

The delete script works ok as well so I won't attach it unless you tell me to. All good, no errors, until I try to delete an entry. Whatever I choose from the list of entries, it will always delete the last one. Note that I have two other inputs echoed out, those will be the "view" and "modify" buttons for the entry.

I really hope this is not JavaScript related because I have no clue of JS. I think this will be of major help to others having this problem. Please let me know if I need to edit my question before downrating. Thanks!

After edit:

This is the delete script, which as I said earlier works fine.

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    echo $id;
    require_once('mysql_connect.php');

    $query = "DELETE FROM oferte Where id_oferta = '$id'";
    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    //header('Location: oferte.php');

}
 else

{
//header('Location: oferte.php');
}


?>
```

The session is started as well, like this:

```
<?php
session_start(); 
?>
```

Comment: its either the delete script of the delete ids in the link, we dont know either

Comment: First, you're missing `session_start();` - Literally a "stick in the spokes" there. Put that at the top above `$email=$_SESSION['email'];`, and try again.

Comment: not missing session_start(), I have it. I just didn't displayed it here.

Comment: Key-riced. Why do I always fall for that, I'll never know. Ok, `session_start();` is in there, then please include it in your question, along with any other little tid bit of information we may need to be made aware of.

Comment: D'ont use `mysql_` functions. They are deprecated. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead

Comment: Hint: in the string you use `\"` to escape `"`.You can use [Heredocs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Comment: Thank you both for your tips! I'll certainly start using mysqli, I know that what I'm currently doing is called "bad practice".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, in this case, is JavaScript related, yes. What I recommend you to do is to simply add a *Remove* link for each item.

```
echo "<a href='oferta.php?id={$oferta['id_oferta']}'>{$oferta['denumire_locatie']}</a>";
echo " - <a href='delete.php?id={$oferta['id_oferta']}'>Remove</a>";
echo "</br>";
```

Comment: I tried that and it works. Thanks for the answer. It is a solution but it would kinda mess up the design that I have in mind so I'm taking the hard path, unfortunately.

Comment: So, you will have to use JS. I recommend that you use jQuery along with it. If you do so, a simple `window.location.href='delete.php?id=' + jQuery(':radio[name=selectie]:checked').val()` at the onClick will do the job.

Comment: I modified that line and now it looks like this:        echo "&nbsp;<input type=\"button\" id=\"sterge\" value=\"Sterge\" onclick=\"window.location.href='delete.php?id=$id' + jQuery(':radio[name=selectie]:checked').val()\" />";        If I click on the button now nothing happens. Is there anything that I need to change?

Comment: Did you add jquery into the page? Also, if you open the console on Chrome, it shows any error?

Comment: As I said I am a complete noob when it comes to JS or any of its frameworks. It's the first time that I use it frankly. Where should I add JQuery to the page and how? Sorry for being such a nuisance.

Comment: Put this on the top of your page `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I added that in the head. I think that's what you mean by top of the page, right? It still does nothing.

Comment: [01:03:38.322] Error in parsing value for 'transition'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://localhost/design/css/style.css:66

Comment: [01:03:38.455] The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol. @ http://localhost/design/oferte.php

Comment: + a few css related things.

Comment: OMG! OMG! It worked, I wasn't able to copy paste right! I guess a change of career is in order. ROFL Thanks a lot for having the patience with me!!!

Answer (score 1):

The reason the last `$id` is deleted is because this line is outside/after the while loop:

```
echo "&nbsp;<input type=\"button\" id=\"sterge\" value=\"Sterge\" onclick=\"window.location.href='delete.php?id=$id'\" />";
```

You want to move this line inside the loop so that you have a button that executes delete for each radio button.

**Update:**

To have links to delete and

```
echo "<input type='radio' name='selectie' value='$id' id='$id'>&nbsp;"; 
echo "<a href='oferta.php?id={$oferta['id_oferta']}'>{$oferta['denumire_locatie']}</a>&nbsp;";
echo "<a href='delete.php?id=$id'>delete</a>";
```

Also I do not think the radio button is needed here at all since you are not really doing anything with it.  You could simply echo out the value of your choice and have these links as follows:

```
echo $oferta['denumire_locatie'] . '&nbsp;'; // replace $oferta['denumire_locatie'] with something of your choice
echo "<a href='oferta.php?id={$oferta['id_oferta']}'>{$oferta['denumire_locatie']}</a>&nbsp;";
echo "<a href='delete.php?id=$id'>delete</a>";
echo "<br />";
```

Comment: Indeed, I tried moving it inside and it works like charm. But I want to have only 3 buttons for the whole list of entries so the user can simply select one and delete/edit or view it so that's not really what I want.

Comment: In that case you need to show us the javascript so that we can propose some answers.  So basically what you want to do is, on click of one of the three buttons, you want to grab the radio button that is selected and pass the id of the selected radio button.

Comment: Well... I know that I'll sound like a complete idiot but I don't have any JavaScript code. What if I replace the onclick thingy with a basic html link? Would this work?

Comment: It would only work if you have "basic html link" for each radio buttons.

Comment: Wasn't me. Can u please copy/paste and edit the radio button bit to show me what u mean by having basic html link for each radio?

Answer (score 0):

Your $id is outside your while() loop.
The last one is getting deleted because the $id has the last one's value when the loops is exited.

Include all your code :

```
echo "</br>";


//echo "<input type=\"button\" id=\"cauta\" value=\"Vizualizeaza\" onclick=\"window.location.href='oferta.php?id={$oferta['id_oferta']}'\" />";
//echo "&nbsp;<input type=\"button\" id=\"cauta\"value=\"Modifica\" onclick=\"window.location.href='modifica.php?id={$oferta['id_oferta']}'\" />";
echo "&nbsp;<input type=\"button\" id=\"sterge\" value=\"Sterge\" onclick=\"window.location.href='delete.php?id=$id'\" />";
```

Inside your while loop.

Answer (score 0):

When the rendered html reaches the browser, it will be something like this:

```
<input type='radio' name='selectie' value='1' id='1'>&nbsp;<a href='oferta.php?id=1'>TEXT</a>
<input type='radio' name='selectie' value='2' id='2'>&nbsp;<a href='oferta.php?id=2'>TEXT</a>
<input type='radio' name='selectie' value='3' id='3'>&nbsp;<a href='oferta.php?id=3'>TEXT</a>
<input type='radio' name='selectie' value='4' id='4'>&nbsp;<a href='oferta.php?id=4'>TEXT</a>
<br/>
<input type="button" id="sterge" value="Sterge" onclick="window.location.href='delete.php?id=5'" />
```

With this markup you won't be able to accomplish what you want without using javascript to update the onclick attribute whenever you select a radio button.

On the other hand, instead of using the client-side *onclick* event you can use the button's default behaviour, which is to submit the form.

You'll just have to set the action attribute:

```
<form method="post" action="http://myurl.php">
```

and write the myurl.php page which will just read the posted variable $_POST['selectie'] and call the delete method with the posted id.

Comment: I know that I could do that but that wouldn't allow me to uncomment the other two lines of code. If I do that the form will have only one action, not three.

Comment: Then the javascript option is definitely the best.